# Reach Delta corporate customer care on the phone

Tags: delta-air-lines

In an effort to get something fair in terms of compensation because of a very unpleasant situation caused by Delta (I described this here: [Refund from Delta for canceled trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169248/refund-from-delta-for-canceled-trip), but that's not of prime importance to know the details) I asked both to booking customer service and to a Delta help desk at the airport how to proceed and they told me to contact "Delta corporate customer care" (in both cases they provided me with a telephone number and told me to find out email address on the website). I was able to find a form on the Delta website that seems to be adequate for my request (and I used it explaining the details of my experience) but I wasn't able to find again and confirm the telephone number I was given. I'd really like to be able to speak to someone even if I am not optimistic about them giving me additional benefit as compensation but reaching them via that telephone number they gave doesn't seem to be a good way to do that: I stayed on the line 4 hours on a Saturday morning and 8 hours on a Friday morning, always in queue. There's something weird in this because that means multiple people were waiting that terrible amount of time, too.

The telephone number I'm calling is +1 8004552720. Is there any other telephone number that I can use to actually get an answer from the appropriate department? I'm aware that for some companies one can take advantage of foreign customer services of the same company that are less busy, but I don't know if that holds for Delta.

Comment: It may be time to let this one go. Even if you manage to get someone on the phone, they will just brush you off. You can write a letter, but we already know where this will go, don't we? The last few times I was trying to contact Delta the wait times were terrible, they just don't have the infrastructure in the moment.  Twitter and Facebook used to work better since it involves public shaming (which they don't like). However, that's been discontinued too. They already gave you something voluntarily, they will not give you any more.

Comment: Unless you are a very frequent traveler (meaning several times a week for years on the account) they're not going to spend a lot of time helping you I'm afraid. They're just too understaffed. If you are, send a personal letter to the CEO, helped my dad once when he had a serious complaint about KLM in the 1990s. And yes, he did travel with them that frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to put it in writing, which makes it more likely your complaint will reach someone authorized to offer compensation. [Write a succinct and clear letter](https://www.elliott.org/answers/how-to-fix-your-own-consumer-problem/) where you explain what happened and request compensation. Include all the necessary details, including your confirmation number and any case or reference number from your previous correspondence with them, but don't ramble on.

Then [send your letter to Delta's contacts](https://www.elliott.org/company-contacts/delta-air-lines-customer-service-contacts/). You can do that online [through their feedback/complaint form](https://www.delta.com/us/en/need-help/overview) (click "Feedback & Complaints" on that page, though you may have already done that if I'm understanding your previous question correctly), by postal mail to their customer care office, or simply email the responsible executive's office ([SVP Reservation Sales and Customer Care](https://www.elliott.org/company-contacts/delta-air-lines-customer-service-contacts/)), and your letter will get forwarded on to the right place.

Maybe they stick with their initial offer of frequent flyer miles or maybe they offer a bit more like a credit toward a future flight. Airlines, for a variety of reasons, are often loathe to give any kind of refund in response to customer complaints like these, so asking for a travel credit may make more sense.